# Numbness in hand after impact in ribs

Tags: muay-thai, injury

After being kicked in the ribs, my hand went numb. It felt like a stinger in Football. The sensation travelled down my arm. Has anyone else experienced this? Is this "normal"? Do I need to see a specialist?

Answer (score 3):

From my anatomical understanding, the only mechanical possibilities for that to happen are either a trauma to the cervical spine (above the shoulders) due to sideways acceleration or a shift of the sternum affecting the upper ribs and the collar bone with surrounding tissue.

That is, given your arm was not above your ribs and hit directly.

Both possibilities involve some impingement of nerves. If there is nothing permanent, like a slight tingling or even numbness in the pinkie, no biggie. If you experience that or pain in the chest or arm while moving full range of motion a day or two later, see a doctor.

Comment: Good advice. There's also the possibility that the kick that hit the ribs also hit the funny bone nerve complex of the elbow on its way. OP might not be remembering that part. Getting checked out by a doctor would be a good precaution.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to see a medical specialist right away.

You experienced an impact in one area of your body.  You then experienced numbness in another part of your body.

A medical specialist will hopefully be able to help determine what occurred.  Their diagnostic testing may include imaging and/or nerve tests.  Neither is particularly painful (and both are much less painful than being kicked in the ribs).

Note that, in my experience, doctors *- just like fighters -* vary greatly in skill level (and their personal opinions of their own skills rarely reflect their actual skills).  Getting a second or third opinion is sometimes needed to help correctly diagnose an issue.

I wish you the best of health.

Comment: I do not see any good medical reason for bothering a doctor with a one-off sensation linked to an impact. As long as it does not persist or is linked with other things that speak for some cardiac connection, it basically is not that different from triggering the funny bone.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Are you a doctor?  Either way, good doctors are not "bothered" by patients.